# Jitter/Sticks on Coaster Brake Hub Wheel

Tags: brakes, wheels, hub, coaster

I am having a major problem trying to get my Coaster Brake Hub reassembled properly...

I've tried with 2 separate wheels, different components and all.

Here's a video of the problem:

I am using the exact same system as this guy in the video:

Do you have any idea of what is STICKING, causing it to jitter like that?

I'm tried reassembling it 4 times now on 2 separate wheels with duplicate components.

I've tried different tensions - it's as if the insides might be a bit worn out or...?

Anyone have any experience on this?

Comment: Is the jitter actually a problem? Does it translate into drag on the wheel when installed on a bike and freewheeling?

Comment: Did you use grease inside ?  If so, what grease exactly ?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - Yes, the jitter is a problem. Sometimes when pedaling/biking, the whole system will LOCK completely and I can't back/front pedal and it turns itself as if it's stuck and then unlocks itself after a turn or half a turn.

At one point it even completely lost "grip" where I'd press hard on the pedals and the whole thing loses grip inside the hub and disconnects letting the system turn without any grip. Really weird!

Comment: @Criggie - I bought specific Bicycle Grease so I think that's fine!

Comment: So actually the hub sometimes applies the brake when it should not, and the 'freewheel' function does not work?

Comment: @NicoI.Collu "bicycle grease" sounds like its for bearings.  For a coaster brake you want high temperature grease to stop it liquifying and running out under load.  However that shouldn't affect the freewheel or the sticking you're experiencing.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - No, I think I am confusing everyone. What happens is that I can turn the pedals and whilst the chain is still turning, there is no rotation on the hub for the wheel to turn. It's like pedaling and the wheel stays in "freewheel" as you mention.

Then the other situation is sometimes after pedaling (and it's working) then when I suddenly go into "freewheel" then the hub locks and starts turning the wheel and pedals without my effort. Like it foregoes the "freewheel" mechanism.

Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Criggie You could absolutely be right about that but currently it's a fresh fix so if it's having problems already now then maybe it's already far beyond damaged?

Do you think possibly that the brakes in the hub are the problem? I did try 2 different sets so I'm not sure how it could be but maybe as both sets were from old wheels.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this model/brand of coaster brake has one, but what I have seen this problem with Bendix coaster brakes and the culprit is a worn retainer spring or a worn driving clutch. Read this article from Sheldon Brown: https://sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I saw it but never read it as it seemed like a poor website but I'm happy I did now.

I tried re-doing everything and at one point, it seemed a lot better but after riding, it started having the same jitter.

I'm afraid I might simply have bad parts..., possibly a worn retainer spring as you mention.

Comment: Parts in a coaster brake do wear out. Replacing the retainer spring is probably your best bet. Also inspect the driver and for wear and damage, especially if the retainer spring is attached to it. If braking is poor, the brake shoes may need to be replaced.

Comment: If you still have it disassembled and clean, pictures of the inner parts (brake pads, clutch, spring, bearings) could be useful in identifying the problem. Slight back and forth movement of the cog also happens to my coaster brake hub; when the bike is off the ground and I spin the pedals, then let go into freewheeling, even the pedals are vibrating a little; but when riding everything works normally and I can't feel the vibrations.

Comment: Do you know the brand of the coaster brake itself? The brand name is usually stamped on the brake arm.